# Shopify message for specific discount in email

Tags: shopify, liquid

This is the code I thought would work but it doesn't:

```
{% for discount in discounts %}
   {% if discount.code == 'testcoupon123' %} 
      You will get a free item!
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Can anyone please explain what is wrong with this?

Comment: Did you printout the used {{ discount.code }} already? Discount codes might be in uppercase instead of lowercase.

Comment: I've tried that unfortunately, no luck! Even if I make it uppercase it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know from using email template codes the discount code field can be multiple discount code(s) for an order, see this document for the brief explanation:

http://docs.shopify.com/manual/settings/notifications/email-variables#discounts

Have you tried using:
{% if discount.first.code == 'testcoupon123' %}